# What does this GTmetrix SSL Error for Wordpress /Cloudflare (full SSL) mean?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, cloudflare

I have wordpress, freshly installed on a digitalocean VPS, with cloudflare pointing at my IP using full SSL.

The website works, but on GTmetrix when I go to test I get:

HTTPS error: SSL connect attempt failed error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

What could this be?